# Does facebook satisfy the 2nd Normalization Form?

Tags: database, facebook, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

According to 2nd normalization form "All non-key attributes are fully functional dependent on the primary key". It's mean all non-key attributes cannot be dependent on a subset of the primary key.
In facebook we can login by email_id, user_name, or mobile_number (so email_id, user_name, or mobile_number are primary keys). And after login by using any of these methods we access the whole account. 
My question is "Is not it partially dependency of non-key attributes on subset of primary key?".
I posted this question in facebook community but didn't get any answer.

Comment: You have tagged this for multiple database engines. Which one are you using?

Comment: This question seems a bit strange,  Facebook is a Service not a Database, its internal data structures may be normalised or de-normalised, you will never know this unless you have the details. What you are talking about is the User Interface, to which normalisation is irrelevant.

Comment: Can only agree with @Mark here; you are mixing together two completely different things. / Apart from that, you can rest assured that in the multitude of databases and database tables Facebook uses there will be enough places where stuff was _deliberately_ not normalized “too the (usual) max”, simply because when you’re dealing with that amount of data less strictly normalized data storage and/or intentional redundancies are _needed_ for acceptable performance in certain scenarios. Your question is therefor way too broad – that’s rather a topic worthy of writing a paper on in computer science.

Comment: you are conflating candidate keys with primary keys.  Two different names, two slightly different concepts.  There is only one primary key chosen, perhaps arbitrarily, from among the candidate keys.

Comment: There is no reason anyone in in the Facebook community should be interested in the database design, unless they are dbas.  And even then, they probably don't infer the database structure by looking at the interface.

Comment: @WalterMitty Re the Facebook community: The user-visible behaviour/interface can be described in many ways and for any particular hypothetical relational way one can discuss the normal forms of the base tables etc in that design. Since each user has some mental model in mind, although one wouldn't say they're interested in database design or interface/behaviour description per se, they are interested in descriptions of the one instance of interface/behaviour insofar as each has one and needs one to use the site.

Comment: Mark has already  made the point that multiple different databses might reside behind the Facebook interface.  Some of them might conform to 2NF while others might not.  You can't tell by looking at the interface.

Comment: I just happened by this old post. Did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

For 2NF non-key attributes cannot be dependent on a *proper* subset of a *candidate* key. (Every set is a subset of itself. A proper subset is a smaller subset.) (There can be multiple candidate keys. One can be picked as primary.)

If all the keys of a relation variable are single columns then the only proper subsets would be the empty set. A column is functionally dependent on no columns if and only if all the values in that column are the same. There are no other proper subsets for columns to be functionally dependent on. So if all columns can have different values and all candidate keys have just one column then a relation variable must be in 2NF.

Functional dependencies and normal forms apply to a particular relation variable. You have to hypothesize a particular design to ask about its particular tables.

A "whole account" is typically not going to be represented (as part of either implementation state or user description) by only one relation variable just because it would have a lot of update anomalies that normalization would get rid of.